# get pathname of the link in jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Hi in my rails  application I need to get path name for ajax URL: if its current path means I can use URL:window.location.pathname similarto that is there any way of getting path name of a link by clicking that link and not going to that link remain in same page?

Comment: Play with http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/QvMLP/1/

Comment: thanks buddy works correctly but i need to modify this to fix with my code thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like below

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">yahoo</a>

    $('a').click(function(e){
    alert(this.href);
    return false;
})
```

See the fiddle from satpal [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/QvMLP/1/)

Instead of alert get the URi in a object and do what ever you want.

Hope this helps...